# PreparedStatement is not working i.e ps.executeUpdate() in JSP

Tags: jsp, jdbc

PreparedStatement is not working.i even checked printing the values just to ensure that empty values are not sent.ps.executeUpdate() is the main area where it is not working.dont know if it is a syntax error.Thank you for your time.

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%!
String fid,lid,gid,did,mn,yid,sid,cid,eid,aid,uid,pid,sttid,paswd;
Connection con;
Statement st;
PreparedStatement ps,ps1;
%>
<%
uid=(String)session.getAttribute("usr");
paswd=(String)session.getAttribute("pswd");
sttid=(String)session.getAttribute("stfid");
int staid=Integer.parseInt(sttid);

try
{
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","sms","vmhs");
String ins="insert into staff values (?,?,?,?)";
ps=con.prepareStatement(ins);
    ps.setString(1,uid);
    ps.setString(2,paswd);
    ps.setInt(3,staid);
    ps.setString(4,"active");
int i=ps.executeUpdate();
String upd="update staffinfo set pword=? where uname=?";
ps1=con.prepareStatement(upd);
ps1.setString(11,uid);
ps1.setString(12,paswd);
int j=ps1.executeUpdate();
if(j>0)
{
%>
<jsp:include page="averify.jsp"/>
<script>
alert("Registration verified successfully");
</script>
<%
}
else
{
%>
<jsp:include page="averify.jsp"/>
<script>
alert("Registration failed.Please check connection and try again");
</script>
<%
}
con.close();
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
e.getMessage();
}
%>
```

Comment: it will be nice to let those who took time to provide solutions to your problem to know if their suggestions helped and in which way. It will also help others to know how this problem was solved. So once you get it working, don't just leave.

Comment: I am sorry i was doing other work.Thank you. it worked.God bless you @MichaelWoyo

Answer (score 0):

am not very sure how many tables you are working with. Your insert statement `"insert into staff values (?,?,?,?)"` was on staff table. Then you are updating `"update staffinfo set pword=? where uname=?"`. Please clarify if they are same tables.

Also, I realized that you are doing this:

```
"update staffinfo set pword=? where uname=?"
ps1.setString(11,uid); // This is username you are passing to password field
ps1.setString(12,paswd);// This is password being passed to username field
int j=ps1.executeUpdate();
```

Do you mean to type this instead:

```
ps1.setString(1, paswd); 
ps1.setString(2, uid); 
int j=ps1.executeUpdate();
```

Please try this. Also, you should always print error message during the development stages because each error is reported back to you with its description. This you should change this line to:

```
catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

So that you can read the exact error message. This will make it easier for you to debug your errors.

Comment: I have checked the error it says invalid column index.the update statement is not being executed.the insert statement has been executed.

Answer (score 0):

how about `Commit`ing the transaction after update ( with `con.commit();` or you can also use `con.setAutoCommit(true);`) :

```
int i=ps.executeUpdate();
String upd="update staffinfo set pword=? where uname=?";
ps1=con.prepareStatement(upd);
ps1.setString(11,uid);
ps1.setString(12,paswd);
int j=ps1.executeUpdate();
con.setAutoCommit(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `.toString()` method like below:

So, instead of:

```
uid=(String)session.getAttribute("usr");
paswd=(String)session.getAttribute("pswd");
sttid=(String)session.getAttribute("stfid");
int staid=Integer.parseInt(sttid);
```

You can try:

```
uid = session.getAttribute("usr").toString();
paswd = session.getAttribute("pswd")toString();
sttid = session.getAttribute("stfid")toString();
int staid = Integer.parseInt(sttid);
```

Why the numbers 11 and 12?

I think it should be 1 and 2 and the change suggested by @Michael.

Instead of:

```
String upd="update staffinfo set pword=? where uname=?";
ps1=con.prepareStatement(upd); 
ps1.setString(11,uid); 
ps1.setString(12,paswd); 
int j=ps1.executeUpdate();
```

It should look something like:

```
String upd="update staffinfo set pword=? where uname=?";
ps1=con.prepareStatement(upd);
ps1.setString(1,paswd);
ps1.setString(2,uid);
int j=ps1.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: the 11 and 12 because it is 11th and 12th colmn in DB

Comment: I think the column number in DB should not matter @Justin. The number of values you are passing should match the number of  "?" placeholder in the query.

Comment: Thank you for the correction.I thought it refers to the colmn no. in DB.Thank you Nitin.God bless you.

Comment: @NitinNair is right. The the first parameter given in the `setString()` method is an index to the `?` which is a placeholder in the `PreparedStatement` object. You should also note that the indexing begins from 1.